# How to retain tab bar after modal segue?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, storyboard

I have 3 View controllers in a tab bar. (my 3 icon). I have another view controller that is accessible from one of the 3 via a button. I do not want this extra view controller to show on the tab bar though.

On clicking the button with a push segue nothing happens, with a modal segue it opens the new page, but the tab bar disappears. (Even though I created a relationship from this new view controller to the tab bar).

How do I get the tab bar to remain? I don't really want to set up a navigation controller between my one view and the other (not on the tab bar) because it's not really hierarchal content.

Is modal actually the right segue to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your views (the views of the 3 views controller) contain the tab bar? If not, you may try transiting from the view to the view of the extra view controller.

see [+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

Answer (score 1):

When you select a Modal segue, the new view is not added as part of the current TabController stack. That's why the tab bar is not visible when you go to this view, and it's why a Push segue does not work for you (you can't push a VC that's not part of the stack).

From the sounds of it, if you want the tab bar to remain visible/useful but don't want to add this VC to the tab bar, what you're really saying is that this VC is a sub-view of one of the original 3 VCs in the tab bar.

In which case you could manage instantiation of your "custom" VC from within one of these original VC's, and add it as a sub-view?

For example if you've got: `Tab1, Tab2, Tab3` and `ExtraView`

in `Tab2 VC` you would init/alloc `SubView` and do: `[self addSubView:ExtraView.view];`

Unfortunately, of course this way you lose Segues, but unless you want to go ahead and set up `Tab2` as nested NavigationController in Storyboard, I think that's your best bet.